# how to detect collision between two sprites in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

i am learning libgdx. i want to create a 2d fps game using libgdx, which is basically no physics environment.  in that case lot of collision will be there (for example lot of bullets hitting multiple objects). i need to check intersecting of every sprite's rectangle with other sprites. in this way there may be thousand sprite's, checking every sprite with other 999 sprites in every time isn't definitely not a good idea.

- libgdx has scene2d which has hit detection api's, is that solve my problem? 
  or
- i should use box2d collision detection?
  or
- is there any other way to detect collision in libgdx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to create a 2d fps game

As much as i know FPS means "First-Person-Shooter" -> a shooter with the first person perspective. That means, that it is 3D.
So pleas clarify what you mean.

Now to the collision detection question:

1. `Scene2D`s hit detection is used for input like touch or
   mouseevents. So it is used to detect, if an `Actor` is touched,
   clicked...
2. `Box2D` is a 2D physic-engine which can not only do collision
   detection for you, but it can also do the collision response as well
   as the physics simulation (gravity and things like that).
3. Libgdx offers the `Intersector` class, which you could use for
   `overlap` tests. The organization/the management of the collision
   detection is up to you.

It would be better if you tell us how your game should work, how your world should be managed etc.
For example, if your world is tilebased, the collision detection between wall and player could be a simple check, if the tile is occupied -> collision, if not -> no collision.
Also it is important to know the shapes of your objects. A rectangle-rectangle collision detection is different from a rectangle-circle collision detection.
So now there are 3 solutions for your problem:
- Use `Box2D` and read tutorials on how to use it
- Do some research on collision detection, read tutorials and take a look at some sample projects
- Give us more informations about the game, its objects, their shapes etc.

Comment: got it.. first my game is like not tile based. i don't know first person shooter is mean's 3d, but my game is like playing call of duty by top view only. so its 2d and there is no need to add physics, and there will be lot of enemy's, vehicles ,bullets , bunkers etc.. so as u mentioned the Intersector class with some collision detection algorithm solve my problem?

Comment: So it is a top down shooter. Well the `Intersector` class has some methods which tell you, if some specific objects overlap. You can take a look at all its methods and you should think about what methods you need. For example the `Intersector` has a method `overlapConvexPolygons`, which can test for a collision between 2 convex polygons. But the management itself (when and how to call the `Intersector` methods) as well as the collision response is up to you.